# firebase delete specific item from Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]don't know how to make user abele to delete his own comment
in android studio using java

all comments played at list

need user to press button delete to delete his comment

and no one can delete comment not his

[![this is my data structure][image]

Comment: What is the exact node you need to delete, comments? Are there any parent nodes or Recipe is a direct child of the root node?

Comment: every recipe have many comments for users i need every user delete hiss owe comment on recipe

Comment: Can you please highlight in the image the exact node you need to delete?

Comment: now u can see i have comments so i need user a delete hiss comment only

Comment: I dee. Have tried something in code?

Answer (score 0):

Solution1:
Add a user's uid in the comment. Use that uid to match the current logged-in user's uid to show delete button in your UI.
data structure for comments: [{uid, name, photoUrl, rating, text}]

Solution2:
The above way should work but essentially all users had delete access to anyone's comment.. it's just that you're not showing the mechanism in UI. for better security I guess you should look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security
something like should work

```
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
      "$item_id" : {
        "comments": {          
          "$comment_id": {            
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null && (data.child('uid').exists() ? (data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) : true)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```